# Getting the standard deviation of an image in Julia

Tags: image, julia

I'm using the Images package and I want to load in an image and get the mean and standard deviation of the pixels in r image.

I tried:

```
using Images, Color, FixedPointNumbers, ImageView, Testimages
img = testimage("mandril")
mean(data(img))
```

The mean worked fine, in fact in IJulia it displays the mean color of the image. However, when I tried to get the standard deviation of the image, I get:

```
std(data(img))

`varm` has no method matching     varm(::Image{RGB{UfixedBase{Uint8,8}},2,Array{RGB{UfixedBase{Uint8,8}},2}}, ::RGB{Float32})
 while loading In[66], in expression starting on line 1

 in var at statistics.jl:162
```

How would one go about getting the standard deviation of the image?

Comment: If you want to check you have done it correctly, you can do so very easily at the command-line with ImageMagick's `identify` command like this: `identify -verbose yourImage.jpg`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `red`, `green` and `blue` to extract the components of image, 
and compute the standard deviation with `std` on the resulting matrices.

```
using Images
using TestImages
using Color
img = testimage("mandril")
data(img)

RGB(
  std(red(img)),
  std(green(img)),
  std(blue(img))
)
# RGB{Float32}(0.22030124f0,0.18964756f0,0.24422659f0)
```

You could also build a 3-dimensional array with all the data,
with `separate`,
and apply `std` on the three 2-dimensional slices corresponding
to the three components, with `mapslices`.

```
vec( mapslices( std, separate(img), [1,2] ) )
```

If you want to figure out why `mean(data(img))` works 
and `std(data(img))` does not (at least, currently), 
you can check which method is called
with `@which`, and read the corresponding code, with `@less`.

```
@which mean(data(img))
# mean(A::AbstractArray{T,N}) at statistics.jl:17

@which std(data(img))
# std(A::AbstractArray{T,N}) at statistics.jl:204

@less mean(data(img))
@less  std(data(img))
```

There are (at least) two problems: first, `sqrt` is not defined for colours,
second, some of the code in `std` assumes that the mean is a `Number`.